# How Delete session by the name

Tags: php

How delete php session by the name 
example i have `session['sec']` and `session['page']` i need to delete `session['page']` with out delete `session['sec']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// for a single variable
unset($_SESSION['session_var']); 

// destroy the Session, not just the data stored!
session_destroy();

// delete the session contents, but keep the session_id and name:
session_unset();
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't be deleting the session in this case, only the session variable. So just do:

```
unset($_SESSION['page']);
```

Comment: Of course now that I look a little closer I can't help but wonder if your using a framework instead of the built-in PHP session handling. Are you?

Comment: Ok, so then probably base PHP. This should work then. The $_SESSION variable is a superglobal. I recommend reading up on it a bit.

Comment: No problem, please remember to vote up answers. It looks like all of us put in roughly the same thing. You could start by voting up each answer once.

Comment: i cant cause Vote Up requires 15 reputation
(click on this box to dismiss)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
unset($_SESSION['page']);
```

Comment: is this gonna delete the session

Comment: this will delete that one session variable, and leave the rest intact.