# How to destroy two different sessions in the same php script?

Tags: php

In my session start script, I choose the session_name and then do a session_start.

```
   $session_name = rand(0,1) ? 'first' : 'second';
   session_name($session_name);
   session_start();
```

The above code runs on every page load. After a few page loads, there will probably be sessions for both session_name 'first' and session_name 'second'.

This is my code which is in my logout script to try and destroy *both* these sessions:

```
session_start();
session_name("first");
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();

session_start();
session_name("second");
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
```

The script above destroys first but not second. If I run the log out script a second time it then destroys the second session, as the first one is already deleted.

How do I destroy sessions for both session names in the same script?

Comment: How do you check if the session is destroyed or not? Your codes says, your second session name haven't even applied to your session.

Comment: The original code was my logout script to destroy the sessions. The sessions are started elsewhere originally

Answer (score 3):

**TRY IT**

```
<?php
    session_name("first");
    session_start();
    echo session_status();
    session_destroy();
    echo session_status();

    session_name("second");
    session_start();
    echo session_status();
    session_destroy();
    echo session_status();
?>
```

I've tested it on xampp and it returns values 2121 meaning session is active, none exist, the session is active, none exist.

I've placed session_name() before session_start() because setting the name as you did doesn't take effect after a session has already been started. I've googled it and it has to do something with the php.ini file where session.auto_start is set to "true".

The explanation and a debate on this topic are found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php - check comments.

**EDITED:**

After reviewing your edit again, you basically don't create two sessions but only one and it starts with a random name "first" or "second". You can destroy a session but the cookie will remain. I've tested your code on xampp and it does exactly that. First, the PHP starts one session and stores a cookie with a time value of "session", after reloading the page it will load one of two options again but this time it will change the existing cookie time to "N/A". You should search for a solution to clear your cookies on your domain after page loads like so:

```
<?php
    $session_name = rand(0,1) ? 'first' : 'second';
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();

    deleteCookies($session_name);

    function deleteCookies($skip_this_one) {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            if ($name == $skip_this_one) {
                //skip
            }else{
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
            }
        }
    }
    //do something inside your session
    //when done, stop the session the way you want
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

This will delete all previous cookies and keep the current session open.

This solution is re-written from here: [how to delete all cookies of my website in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310558/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-my-website-in-php)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Read up on session names.

Comment: Then your question has probably been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703721/how-delete-session-by-the-name

Comment: That's whole point of my question. Doing that for *two* different sessions in the same script doesn't work. It works fine for one session.

Comment: I've tested some code for you and edited my post. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code

```
<?php unset($_SESSION['name']); // will delete just the name data
session_destroy(); // will delete ALL data associated with that user. 
?>
```